# Cannot find CVSROOT for file

Tags: intellij-idea, cvs

We had trouble with our CVS server connection. Also I've migrated from IDEA 10 to 11 version. Now I have problem with CVS. I cannot update, add or commit project cause of this exception:

> Error: Cannot find CVSROOT for file C:\New\SMDPO

But configuration of CVS is OK and I have sucess test connection.

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Thanks

Upd: I have remote CVS server on Linux. I use Windows 7. Everything was same and worked before.

Comment: What protocol is used? Did you configure it as local root by mistake?

Comment: Is `C:\New\ ` something you checked out (in this place) from CVS, or a copy you made locally?

Comment: Yes, this all work at previous 10 version and before the collapse with CVS. The protocol is :pserver. " Did you configure it as local root by mistake?" What I need to do?

Comment: What's stored in `CVS/Root` file inside the project root?

Comment: YEEE! You are great! This is strange but I lost my CVS folder))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the missing `CVS` folder inside the project root. IDE is looking for `CVS/Root` file.

Comment: and? what is the solution? :)

Comment: @Spring make a checkout from the version control so that a working copy with VCS metadata appears there.

Answer (score 4):

Select from menu: "VCS > CVS > Migrate CVS Root...". Fixed it for me after migrating (importing) a project from Eclipse workspace.